# jpa doesn't update data in db when entity changes?

Tags: java, jpa

More precisely, it does this within the method, but at the end of the method, these changes are not saved. I cannot make it @Transaction. it is multi-threaded and adds dependent entities.
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Inside a method, an entity **that is fetched from repository**, is in managed JPA state. This means that changes been done at this entity when the method finishes will be persisted in Database automatically. For this to happen though it is neccessary that the method is inside a Transaction. So this method or some other method that has called this method must have `@Transactional` in order for a transaction to be around the method.

If you don't want to have on this method or some other method that calls this method the `@Transactional` then your only chance of achieving what you want is to manually store the entity before your method ends. You should at this point do `yourRepository.save(yourUpdatedEntity);`